# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool

Tags: java, maven, raspberry-pi

Im trying to install [this java web app](https://bitbucket.org/insideo/piano-player/src/master/) on a raspberry pi 4b running raspbian lite x64

I'm able to successfully build using `mvn clean package`
but when i try to run using

```
    java \
        -Xms4m \
        -Xmx64m \
        -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/conf/log4j.xml \
        -jar target/piano-player-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar \
        /conf/piano-player.yml
```

I get the following error
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool`

I already downgraded openJDK, Node, and Mavin

```
openjdk version "17.0.9"
Node v16.0.0
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.5.0
```

I tried setting the jetty-util dependency in the pom file to `9.3.14.v20161028` but got a bunch of `module not found` errors while building

[dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmY2j.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This codebase has been updated to use the Java module system, so it requires a little different syntax to launch. Try something like this (where CONF_DIR is the location of logback.xml and piano-player.yml and LIB_DIR is where all the jar files are located:

```
$ java -Xms4m -Xmx64m \
  --class-path "${CONF_DIR}" \
  --module-path "${LIB_DIR}" \
  --module org.randomcoder.piano \
  "${CONF_DIR}/piano-player.yml"
```

This should work for you -- it's what I've been using for about the last year or so.